# How to use a repeater as wireless card?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I want to use a wireless repeater as wifi card for computer. I want to connect the repeater and computer using ethernet and i want the repeater to serve as a wireless card for computer running linux. Is it posible?

Comment: Do you really mean repeater, or perhaps Access Point? They're different. A repeater only repeats whatever floats in the air, without any network connectivity whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is get an Ethernet-only box connected into a wireless network, then yes, this can work.

In contrast, if you wanted the Linux box to see this device as if it were a locally connected WLAN card and be able to configure it from the normal WLAN tools and run Wi-Fi network scanners and run 802.11 monitor mode packet captures and aircrack-ng on it, then No. When you want to mess with the settings on the repeater or see its signal strength or tell it to join a different network, you'll have to use a web browser just like reconfiguring any other consumer wireless router.